# OpenVPN Connect profile path

Tags: applications, vpn, path

I'm trying to find the path to imported profiles in openvpn connect app in macos. I tried

> /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/OpenVPN Connect/

but nothing there.

I'm using OpenVPN connect version 2.7.1 (company enforced)

Answer (score 8):

Normally they should show up in

```
~/Library/Application Support/OpenVPN Connect/profiles
```

where `~` is your home folder

Comment: even this directory is empty !

Comment: Worked fine for me on macOS Monterey - OpenVPN Connet Version 3.3.6 (4368)

Comment: Works on Ventura too